# Installing Application on iPhone: Resource has been modified

Tags: iphone, resources, installation

I am working on a simple iPhone application and when I run my app on my machine it installs on the device, but when I try it on a Windows machine using an ad-hoc distribution profile, it shows an error: "Application couldn't be installed because a resource has been modified."
I have 2 iPhones and have tested the same app; on iPhone 2G it works fine, but on the 3G it shows the error I have written above.
I tried to change the certificate and provisioning profiles, but no luck.
Please let me know where I am mistaken.

Thanks.
Steve

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug related to this with Xcode 3.2.2, which might cause this problem [link to forum](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/39173-same-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-deleted-error-xcode-3-2-2-a.html)